# How to fetch an image on my server using php if echo

Tags: php, html

I want to display an image on my website only when someone searches for category flowers.. now the flowers category is numbered as 24 in my database therefore, my website auto generates the url below when searching for flowers:

http://example.com/search/category=24+distance=25+geo_lat=+geo_lng=+sort_by=

How can I make an image show based on the above? I tried the below code but not working..

```html
<?php

    if ($category['flowers']){
      echo "<img src='flowers.png' alt='image'/>" ;
    }
?>
```

EDIT--

I was thinking, would it be easier to just fetch the image on site generated url rather than on category?

So instead of using $category to fetch the image, we use the url generated by the site http://example.com/search/category=24+distance=25+geo_lat=+geo_lng=+sort_by=

to get the image? How can I accomplish this? I tried using suvojit_007 code like this

```html
if ($url['mysite.com/..../hdhd.png']){  //<---site generated url

    echo "<img src='" . $url ."' alt='image'/>" ;  

}
```

But it didnt work, I might have done this wrong..

EDIT-- FULL SEARCH.PHP SOURCE CODE

```html
<form action="<?php echo site_url('show/getresult_ajax/grid/'.$per_page);?>" method="post" id="advance-search-form" class="form">

                <div class="s-widget">
                    <h5><i class="fa fa-search color"></i>&nbsp; <?php echo lang_key('search_filters'); ?></h5>
                    <!-- Form Group -->
                    <div class="widget-content search">

                        <!-- Search Widget -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <div class="input-group">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="<?php echo lang_key('type_anything');?>" value="<?php echo (isset($data['plainkey']))?rawurldecode($data['plainkey']):'';?>" name="plainkey">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-color"><?php echo lang_key('search'); ?></button>
                            </span>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <?php if($filter_type=='advanced_options_with_country_state'){?>
                        <?php $country_temp = (isset($data['country']))?$data['country']:'';?>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <select name="country" id="country" class="form-control chosen-select">
                                <option data-name="" value=""><?php echo lang_key('select_country');?></option>
                                <?php foreach (get_all_locations_by_type('country')->result() as $row) {
                                    $sel = ($row->id==$country_temp)?'selected="selected"':'';
                                    ?>
                                    <option data-name="<?php echo $row->name;?>" value="<?php echo $row->id;?>" <?php echo $sel;?>><?php echo lang_key($row->name);?></option>
                                <?php }?>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <?php if($state_active=='yes'){?>
                        <div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                 <?php $state_temp = (isset($data['state']))?$data['state']:'';?>
                                <select name="state" id="state" class="form-control chosen-select">
                                    <option value="<?php echo $state_temp?>" selected="selected"></option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php }?>

                        <div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <?php $city_field_type = 'dropdown'; ?>
                                <input type="hidden" id="selected_city" value="<?php echo(set_value('selected_city')!='')?set_value('selected_city'):'';?>">
                                <?php if ($city_field_type=='dropdown') {?>
                                <?php $city_temp = (isset($data['city']))?$data['city']:'';?>
                                <select name="city" id="city_dropdown" class="form-control chosen-select">                                        
                                    <option value=""><?php echo lang_key('select_one');?></option>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $city_temp?>" selected="selected"></option>
                                </select>
                                <?php }else {?>
                                <input type="text" id="city" name="city" value="<?php echo(set_value('city')!='')?set_value('city'):'';?>" placeholder="<?php echo lang_key('city');?>" class="form-control" >
                                <span class="help-inline city-loading">&nbsp;</span>
                                <?php }?>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <?php }else{?>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <?php $city_temp = (isset($data['city']))?$data['city']:'any';?>
                            <select name="city" class="form-control chosen-select">
                                <option data-name="" value="any"><?php echo lang_key('any_city');?></option>
                                <?php foreach (get_all_cities_by_use()->result() as $row) {
                                    $sel = ($row->id==$city_temp)?'selected="selected"':'';
                                    ?>
                                    <option data-name="<?php echo $row->name;?>" class="cities city-<?php echo $row->parent;?>" value="<?php echo $row->id;?>" <?php echo $sel;?>><?php echo lang_key($row->name);?></option>
                                <?php }?>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <?php }?>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <?php $category_temp = (isset($data['category']))?$data['category']:-1;?>
                            <select name="category" class="form-control chosen-select">
                                <option value="any"><?php echo lang_key('any_category');?></option>
                                <?php foreach ($categories as $row) {
                                    $sub = ($row->parent!=0)?'--':'';
                                    $sel = ($category_temp==$row->id)?'selected="selected"':'';
                                    ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $row->id;?>" <?php echo $sel;?>><?php echo $sub.lang_key($row->title);?></option>
                                <?php
                                }?>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label><?php echo lang_key('distance_around_my_position'); ?>: <span class="price-range-amount-view" id="amount"></span></label>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="findLocation()" class="btn btn-orange btn-xs find-my-location"><i class="fa fa-location-arrow"></i></a>
                            <div id="slider-price-sell" class="price-range-slider"></div>
                            <input type="hidden" id="price-slider-sell" name="distance" value="">
                            <input type="hidden" id="geo_lat" name="geo_lat" value="<?php echo (isset($data['geo_lat']))?$data['geo_lat']:''; ?>">
                            <input type="hidden" id="geo_lng" name="geo_lng" value="<?php echo (isset($data['geo_lng']))?$data['geo_lng']:''; ?>">
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group">
                            <?php $sort_by_temp = (isset($data['sort_by']))?$data['sort_by']:'';?>
                            <?php $options = array('rating_asc','rating_desc','id_asc','id_desc');?>
                            <select name="sort_by" class="form-control chosen-select">
                                <option value=""><?php echo lang_key('order_by');?></option>
                                <?php foreach ($options as $row) {
                                    $sel = ($row==$sort_by_temp)?'selected="selected"':'';
                                    ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $row;?>" <?php echo $sel;?>><?php echo lang_key($row);?></option>
                                <?php }?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Button -->
                        <button class="btn btn-blue submit-search-button" type="submit"><?php echo lang_key('search');?></button>&nbsp;
                        <button class="btn btn-default reset" type="reset"><?php echo lang_key('reset');?></button>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </form>

            <?php render_widgets('side_bar_search_page');?>
        </div>
        


    </div> <!-- end of left bar -->

    <!-- Mainbar column -->
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9">
      <h5><span style="position:relative;top:12px;"><?php echo lang_key('results'); ?></span>
        <div class="pull-right list-switcher">
          <a class="result-grid" href="#"><i class="fa fa-th "></i></a>
          <a class="result-list" href="#"><i class="fa fa-th-list "></i></a>
          <a class="result-map" href="#"><i class="fa fa-map-marker "></i></a>
          <form id="toggle-form" action="<?php echo site_url('show/toggle/map');?>" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="url" value="<?php echo current_url();?>">
          </form>
        </div>
      </h5>
      <span class="results">   
      </span>
      <div class="ajax-loading recent-loading"><img src="<?php echo theme_url();?>/assets/img/loading.gif" alt="loading..."></div>
      <a href="" class="load-more-recent btn btn-blue" style="width:100%"><?php echo lang_key('load_more_posts');?></a>
    </div> <!-- end of main content -->
</div><!-- end of row -->
<?php
//added on version  1.7
$isSsl = (strpos('-'.base_url(), 'https://')>0)?'1':'0';
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1; //&& ua.indexOf("mobile");

    // added on version 1.5
    var isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);
    var isSsl = '<?php echo $isSsl;?>';
    //end

    jQuery(window).resize(function(){
        if(!isAndroid) {
            $('.chosen-select').select2({
                theme: "classic"
            });
        }
    });

    var per_page = '<?php echo $per_page;?>';
    var recent_count = '<?php echo $per_page;?>';

    $(document).ready(function(){
        if(!isAndroid) {
            $('.chosen-select').select2({
                theme: "classic"
            });
        }

        <?php $distance = (isset($data['distance']))? $data['distance'] != '' ?  $data['distance']  :  $this->config->item('default_distance') : $this->config->item('default_distance');  ?>

        var distance = parseInt('<?php echo $distance; ?>');

        var distance_unit = '<?php echo lang_key(get_settings("business_settings", "show_distance_in", "miles")); ?>';

        $("#slider-price-sell").slider({

            min: <?php echo $this->config->item('min_distance');?>,

            max: <?php echo $this->config->item('max_distance');?>,

            value: distance,

            slide: function (event, ui) {

                $("#price-slider-sell").val(ui.value);
                $("#amount").html( ui.value + ' ' + distance_unit );

            }

        });
        $("#price-slider-sell").val(distance);
        $("#amount").html($( "#slider-price-sell" ).slider( "value") + ' ' + distance_unit);


    });

  // updated on version 1.5
    function findLocation()
    {
        if(isChrome==true && isSsl==0)
        {
            var r = confirm("<?php echo lang_key('location_chorome_msg')?>");
            if(r==true)
            {
                $.get("//ipinfo.io", function(response) {
                var arr = response.loc.split(",");

                        $('#geo_lat').val(arr[0]);
                        $('#geo_lng').val(arr[1]);

                }, "jsonp");
                
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(!!navigator.geolocation) {

                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

                    $('#geo_lat').val(position.coords.latitude);
                    $('#geo_lng').val(position.coords.longitude);


                });

            } else {
                alert('No Geolocation Support.');
            }            
        }
    }
    //end

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){

        var site_url = '<?php echo site_url();?>';
        jQuery('#country').change(function(){
            // jQuery('#city').val('');
            // jQuery('#selected_city').val('');
            var val = jQuery(this).val();
            
            var loadUrl = site_url+'/show/get_locations_by_parent_ajax/'+val;

            jQuery.post(
                loadUrl,
                {},
                function(responseText){
                    <?php if($state_active=='yes'){?>
                    jQuery('#state').html(responseText);
                    var sel_country = '<?php echo (isset($data["country"]))?$data["country"]:"";?>';
                    var sel_state   = '<?php echo (isset($data["state"]))?$data["state"]:"";?>';
                    if(val==sel_country)
                    jQuery('#state').val(sel_state);
                    else
                    jQuery('#state').val('');
                    jQuery('#state').focus();
                    jQuery('#state').trigger('change');
                    <?php }else{?>
                    var sel_country = '<?php echo (isset($data["country"]))?$data["country"]:"";?>';
                    var sel_city   = '<?php echo (isset($data["selected_city"]))?$data["selected_city"]:"";?>';
                    var city   = '<?php echo (isset($data["city"]))?$data["city"]:"";?>';
                    if(city_field_type=='dropdown')
                    populate_city(val); //populate the city drop down
                    if(val==sel_country)
                    {
                        jQuery('#selected_city').val(sel_city);
                        jQuery('#city_dropdown').val(city);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        jQuery('#selected_city').val(sel_city);
                        jQuery('#city_dropdown').val('');            
                    }
                    <?php }?>

                }
            );
         }).change();

        var city_field_type =  'dropdown' ;

            jQuery('#state').change(function(){
                <?php if($state_active=='yes'){?>
                var val = jQuery(this).val();
                var sel_state   = '<?php echo (isset($data["state"]))?$data["state"]:"";?>';
                var sel_city   = '<?php echo (isset($data["selected_city"]))?$data["selected_city"]:"";?>';
                var city   = '<?php echo (isset($data["city"]))?$data["city"]:"";?>';
                
                if(city_field_type=='dropdown')
                populate_city(val); //populate the city drop down

                if(val==sel_state)
                {
                    jQuery('#selected_city').val(sel_city);
                    jQuery('#city').val(city);
                }
                else
                {
                    jQuery('#selected_city').val('');
                    jQuery('#city').val('');            
                }
                <?php }?>

            }).change();

    });

function populate_city(parent) {
    var site_url = '<?php echo site_url();?>';
    var loadUrl = site_url+'/show/get_city_val_dropdown_by_parent_ajax/'+parent;
        jQuery.post(
            loadUrl,
            {},
            function(responseText){
                jQuery('#city_dropdown').html(responseText);
                var sel_state   = '<?php echo (isset($data["state"]))?$data["state"]:"";?>';
                var sel_country = '<?php echo (isset($data["country"]))?$data["country"]:"";?>';
                var sel_city    = '<?php echo (isset($data["city"]))?$data["city"]:"";?>';
                <?php if($state_active=='yes'){?>
                if(parent==sel_state)
                {
                  jQuery('#city_dropdown').val(sel_city);
                  if(!isAndroid) {
                    $("#city_dropdown").select2("val", sel_city);
                  }                  
                }
                else
                {
                  jQuery('#city_dropdown').val('');
                  if(!isAndroid) {
                    $("#city_dropdown").select2("val", '');
                  }                                    
                }
                <?php }else{?>
                if(parent==sel_country)
                {
                  jQuery('#city_dropdown').val(sel_city);
                  if(!isAndroid) {
                    $("#city_dropdown").select2("val", sel_city);
                  }                  
                }
                else
                {
                  jQuery('#city_dropdown').val('');
                  if(!isAndroid) {
                    $("#city_dropdown").select2("val", '');
                  }                                    
                }
                <?php }?>
            }
        );
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  jQuery('.reset').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('#advance-search-form input').each(function(){
      jQuery(this).val('');
    });

    jQuery('select[name=city]').select2("val", "any");
    jQuery('select[name=category]').select2("val", "any");
    jQuery('select[name=sort_by]').select2("val", "");
    
    jQuery('#advance-search-form').submit();
  });

  jQuery('#advance-search-form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var loadUrl = jQuery('#advance-search-form').attr('action');
    var data = jQuery('#advance-search-form').serialize();
    jQuery('.recent-loading').show(); 

    jQuery.post(
        loadUrl,
        data,
        function(result){          
           //document.title = result.title;
           if(result.url!=window.location){
             window.history.pushState({path:result.url},'',result.url);
           }
           
           jQuery('.results').html(result.content);
           jQuery('.recent-loading').hide(); 
           
           if(jQuery('.results .img-responsive').length<recent_count)
           {
                jQuery('.load-more-recent').hide();
           }
           fix_grid_height();
          
        },
        'json'
    );

  });

  jQuery('.load-more-recent').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var next = parseInt(recent_count)+parseInt(per_page);

      var url = jQuery('#advance-search-form').attr('action');
      url = url.replace('/'+recent_count,'/'+next);
      jQuery('#advance-search-form').attr('action',url);
      recent_count = next;

      jQuery('#advance-search-form').submit();  
  });

  jQuery('.result-grid').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      jQuery('.result-grid').addClass('selected');
      jQuery('.result-list').removeClass('selected');

      var url = jQuery('#advance-search-form').attr('action');
      var action = url.replace('/list/','/grid/');
      jQuery('#advance-search-form').attr('action',action);
      jQuery('#advance-search-form').submit();
    });

  jQuery('.result-list').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('.result-grid').removeClass('selected');
    jQuery('.result-list').addClass('selected');

    var url = jQuery('#advance-search-form').attr('action');
    var action = url.replace('/grid/','/list/');
    jQuery('#advance-search-form').attr('action',action);
    jQuery('#advance-search-form').submit();

  });

  jQuery('.result-map').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('#toggle-form').submit();
  });

  var initialURL = location.href;

});


</script>
```

The database table of categories is dbc_categories and it has row id which in the flowers case is id 24

Comment: How is your flower image stored? If you have it stored as a value in a table in a MySQL database, you would just query that table inside your conditional. This would be done using MySQLi or PDO. If you're just looking to output an image based on a conditional, the above will work assuming you set `$category` correctly. For what it's worth, your conditional (in your case) appears to be based off `$_GET`. That is to say, `if($_GET['category'] == 24)`.

Comment: the image is stored in a directory on my server, same directory as the website.

Comment: @Nubbie check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($category['flowers']){  //<-----your condition

    $url = "mysite.com/..../hdhd.png";  //<---site generated url

    echo "<img src='" . $url ."' alt='image'/>" ;  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use following code :-**

```
   <?php
        $category['flowers'] = 'rose';
        if ($category['flowers']){
            echo "<img src='flowers.png' alt='img not found' />" ;
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: tried it but not working, the image does show but on all categories. I need it to show only on http://example.com/search/category=24+distance=25+geo_lat=+geo_lng=+sort_by=